# Open a random popup div with random with different class number jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As an all-time JS beginner, I'm trying to show a different popup each time on button click.

Tried a bunch of different things but nothing worked so far...

Each popup div has a class "pop" + a number afterward, so "pop1", "pop2"... On click, I want to show a different popup in random order.

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <img class="" src="images/button.png">
</div>

<div class="pop1 hide">
<div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="success-inner">
            <div class="popup-info-text">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>
            <div class="play-btn">
                Redeem it now
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end pop1 -->
<div class="pop2 hide">
<div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="success-inner">
            <div class="popup-info-text">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>
            <div class="play-btn">
                Redeem it now
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end pop2 -->
```

my jQuery so far to show/hide the popup:

```
   //show popup on click with a delay
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".pop").removeClass("hide");
        $(".pop").addClass("show");
        $(".pop").show();
        $(".success-msg").show();
    }, 3800);
```

Trying to add new jQuery code to randomize the popup by allowing a different popup show:

```
$('.button ').click(function () {
        class_is=$(this).attr('class').match(/block-[0-2]/,'');

        $('.pop div').each(function() {
         if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(class_is)!==-1) {
       $(this).toggleClass('show');
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('show');
         }
        })
    });
```

Every advice is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done using just `removeClass()/addClass()` with the help of `rand()` to generate random numbers, like :

**Simple solution :**

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  var global_selector = $("[class^='pop_']");
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * global_selector.length) + 1;

  global_selector.addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
  $(".pop_" + random).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.info-msg,
.success-msg,
.warning-msg,
.error-msg {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.info-msg {
  color: #059;
  background-color: #BEF;
}

.success-msg {
  color: #270;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
}

.warning-msg {
  color: #9F6000;
  background-color: #FEEFB3;
}

.error-msg {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFBABA;
}


/* Just for CodePen styling - don't include if you copy paste */

html {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 25px;
}

body {
  width: 640px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">CLICK ME</div>

<div class="pop_1 hide">
  <div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end pop1 -->
<div class="pop_2 hide">
  <div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pop_3 hide">
  <div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Non-successive random solution (Avoiding successive random numbers):**

```js
var random = 1;

$('.button').click(function() {
  var global_selector = $("[class^='pop_']");
  random = generateNonSuccessiveRand(1, global_selector.length, random);

  global_selector.addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
  $(".pop_" + random).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
});

function generateNonSuccessiveRand(min, max, previous) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

  while (rand === previous) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min
  }

  return rand;
}
```

```css
.info-msg,
.success-msg,
.warning-msg,
.error-msg {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.info-msg {
  color: #059;
  background-color: #BEF;
}

.success-msg {
  color: #270;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
}

.warning-msg {
  color: #9F6000;
  background-color: #FEEFB3;
}

.error-msg {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFBABA;
}


/* Just for CodePen styling - don't include if you copy paste */

html {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 25px;
}

body {
  width: 640px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">CLICK ME</div>

<div class="pop_1 hide">
  <div class="error-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end pop1 -->
<div class="pop_2 hide">
  <div class="success-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pop_3 hide">
  <div class="info-msg">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div class="success-inner">
      <div class="popup-info-text">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
      <div class="play-btn">
        Redeem it now 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score 0):

There is a million ways to achieve this... Basically, you need a way to identify which 'pop' you want to display, obviously lol.

Here is a simple pen showing the most basic way of doing it. It uses a variable to keep a count of each time the button div is clicked and used as the index to determine which 'pop' to show.

https://codepen.io/jthomas077/pen/BOemQQ

```
var popCntr = 0;

$('.button').on('click touchend', function (e) 
{
    $('.pop').hide().eq(popCntr).show();

    popCntr++;

    $('.pop-cntr').html(popCntr);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```